# Do snapshot tests replace "standard" tests?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, snapshot

I am doing some unit tests for my React components but I have never used snapshots before. When I see some code examples on github, many developers use exclusively snapshot testing other than "standard tests" like this: https://react-testing-examples.com/

When I read about snapshots, they say "Snapshot tests are a very useful tool whenever you want to make sure your UI does not change unexpectedly.", so I don't understand if I could use exclusively snapshots to test my components or not.